# R: how do you add a red dot line in residual plot for funnel type shape?

Tags: r, regression

I want to add a red dot line in the residual scatterplot in R to look like the one from SPSS.

So it is clear for you to say there is a funnel type pattern in the residual plot, then the residual does not have a constant variance?

[image: Residual plot in R with no red dot line]

[image: Residual plot in SPSS which has red dot line]

Comment: can you point us to documentation that describes how to add these lines to a graph?  In general the recommendation for graphical evaluation of heteroscedasticity in residuals linear models is to use a *scale-location* plot: `plot(fitted_model, which=3)`